# Select rows of a data.frame that contain only numbers in a certain column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, numeric

How to select only the rows that contain a number in column *b*.

```
a <- c(1,5,3,1,-8,6,-1)
b <- c(4,-2,1,0,"c",2,"DX")

df <- data.frame(a,b)
df

#    a  b
# 1  1  4
# 2  5 -2
# 3  3  1
# 4  1  0
# 5 -8  c
# 6  6  2
# 7 -1  DX
```

The output should look like this:

```
#    a  b
# 1  1  4
# 2  5 -2
# 3  3  1
# 4  1  0
# 5  6  2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `grep`:

```
df[grep("[[:digit:]]", df$b), ]
#  a  b
#1 1  4
#2 5 -2
#3 3  1
#4 1  0
#6 6  2
```

Answer (score 6):

This should be faster (it doesn't use regex)

```
df[!is.na(as.numeric(df$b)), ]
```

Comment: You are right, your solution is faster but it produces a warning: `as.numeric("a")` and is not working when the column contains a `factor` `as.numeric(factor("a"))` (as in this example, because `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` is missing).